# How to make \nwarrow bigger?

Tags: arrows

I want to know how to make the tilted arrow (`\nwarrow`) bigger. I have tried `\large`, but nothing works. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean `\nearrow`?

Comment: No, the command I used was \nwarrow. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far ...

Comment: This is the code \begin{math}
\hspace{5cm}\textsf{\textbf{T}}
\underbrace{(a)}_\nwarrow \\
\end{math}

Comment: Welcome: Take a look here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. There are many thinks to be improved in your code but you have to give an example like these that are described in this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be clunkier than necessary, but it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx} % amsmath for \text, graphicx for \scalebox

\newcommand{\bignwarrow}{\text{\scalebox{2}{\ensuremath{\nwarrow}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{math} 
\textsf{\textbf{T}} \underbrace{(a)}_\bignwarrow \\ 
\end{math} 

\end{document}
```

[image]